# How to animate a twisting beam

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, keyframes

I have a cone external gear rotating around the inside of a cylindrical internal gear, I have the cone rotating on its point and I want the beam its standing on to twist with its rotation, I have it set up so that the beam and the cylindrical internal gear are two separate objects. The beam has a bezier curve through the middle. My problem is I dont know how to animate it to move this way, I tried editing it in the side to side motion but that didnt grab when i put them in keyframes.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A4kGHSKqgsDwgf4ckxJFcmgMTG3ZvOfD/view?usp=sharing

Heres a short video showing what I have right now and the motion im aiming for.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your description, but let bottom flat part rotate in cylindrical cone direction but limited to one axis ...

In this example the bottom flat part is using two **Constraints**

- **Track to** > Empty
- **Limit Rotation** > enable Y, Z

Plus to let it work change under object properties Rotation mode to **ZYX Euler**

[image]

[image]

### Edit

Since your *Cone* (in shared .blend) is animated with f-curve you can just open *Properties panel* (N) in *Viewport* and right click over **Rotation Y** field to open contextual menu and choose **Copy as New driver**, than select *Bezier Curve* in edit mode middle point and under *Properties* again right click over **Tilt** field and from contextual menu choose **Paste Driver**

Comment: Yes this is basically the movement Im shooting for, but also with the flat part bending itself and not moving on the far sides.  How did you set up the empty and the cone to rotate this way, I believe I did it differently and am not able to track my empty like this, im still very new to animation.

Comment: I was also curious how you animated the cone (you can share your file via https://blend-exchange.com ... I will share my file, but my animation is probably the best one, my Empty is parented to Circle, but can be parented to cone ... the point here is to have something to direct and limit it. To rotate just middle part (and keep end points) is possible, but I'm not sure if it is possible with bezier curve. I tried to Hook middle point and assign constraint to Hook (another Empty), but Hook control only Location not Rotation. I'm going to choose bones, but if not - mesh is possible for you?

Comment: I animated mine by first making a keyframe with the cone rotated to be touching the inside of the cylinder, I think it was -10.5 degrees in the X direction, then reseting it, making another key 20 frames later at -10.5 degrees in the Y direction, repeated that process until it made a full circle, then I just cycled it.

Comment: I edited my A (missing info ZYX Euler) and simple way to use driver for your file setup. If you need more info let see know.

Comment: Im looking at your file, how did you get the cone to rotate like that.  I parented my empty to the circle using without inverse,  then set my cone to track to the empty, along the Z, but I dont see how you got it to spin, I dont see any animation in the timeline or graph editor.

Comment: Sorry for that - I set a driver (violet field) to animate rotation ... you can set driver if you type expression #frame*0.05 in the Z Rotation ... if you click into my violet field it is written there (just without hashtag "#" symbol, since driver is set). Circle is using expression #frame*0.025 ... half of cone value, I don't know why, this is the only way I know how to use simple drivers :)

Comment: Yeah I tried copying exactly how you did it and I just cant figure out why mine is not working.  I cant even get my cone to spin and rotate properly.

Comment: You can try to share current state and I can check what is missing ... or have you tried to copy-paste driver in your original blend? Or you can use my file and change data block of my cone object and assign cone of your data-block.